# Is there a better way to write this Sumifs piece of code?

Tags: vba, loops, sumifs

I have 13 columns in which i use a sumif column from another data sheet. It is pretty simple and straight forward but not quite sure how I can write it more properly.

I have 13 months in my data sheet in columns ranging from N, Q, T (...) AX. Thus, 2 columns in between that I do not need. From row 4 to 7000 I have different customers in no specific order, so I want to make a simple sumIf code.

My code is already working but seems odd and an overkill. Do you guys know how I can write this in a smaller and smarter piece of code using notation like For j = 1 to 13 (...)?

Here is my code:

```
Range("C4").Cells(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(data.Range("N3:N50000"), data.Range("B3:B50000"), Range("B4").Cells(i, 1), data.Range("J3:J50000"), "Behold", data.Range("D3:D50000"), Range("AB4").Cells(i, 1))
    Range("D4").Cells(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(data.Range("Q3:Q50000"), data.Range("B3:B50000"), Range("B4").Cells(i, 1), data.Range("J3:J50000"), "Behold", data.Range("D3:D50000"), Range("AB4").Cells(i, 1))
    Range("E4").Cells(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(data.Range("T3:T50000"), data.Range("B3:B50000"), Range("B4").Cells(i, 1), data.Range("J3:J50000"), "Behold", data.Range("D3:D50000"), Range("AB4").Cells(i, 1))
    Range("F4").Cells(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(data.Range("W3:W50000"), data.Range("B3:B50000"), Range("B4").Cells(i, 1), data.Range("J3:J50000"), "Behold", data.Range("D3:D50000"), Range("AB4").Cells(i, 1))
    Range("G4").Cells(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(data.Range("Z3:Z50000"), data.Range("B3:B50000"), Range("B4").Cells(i, 1), data.Range("J3:J50000"), "Behold", data.Range("D3:D50000"), Range("AB4").Cells(i, 1))
    Range("H4").Cells(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(data.Range("AC3:AC50000"), data.Range("B3:B50000"), Range("B4").Cells(i, 1), data.Range("J3:J50000"), "Behold", data.Range("D3:D50000"), Range("AB4").Cells(i, 1))
    Range("I4").Cells(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(data.Range("AF3:AF50000"), data.Range("B3:B50000"), Range("B4").Cells(i, 1), data.Range("J3:J50000"), "Behold", data.Range("D3:D50000"), Range("AB4").Cells(i, 1))
    Range("J4").Cells(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(data.Range("AI3:AI50000"), data.Range("B3:B50000"), Range("B4").Cells(i, 1), data.Range("J3:J50000"), "Behold", data.Range("D3:D50000"), Range("AB4").Cells(i, 1))
    Range("K4").Cells(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(data.Range("AL3:AL50000"), data.Range("B3:B50000"), Range("B4").Cells(i, 1), data.Range("J3:J50000"), "Behold", data.Range("D3:D50000"), Range("AB4").Cells(i, 1))
    Range("L4").Cells(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(data.Range("AO3:AO50000"), data.Range("B3:B50000"), Range("B4").Cells(i, 1), data.Range("J3:J50000"), "Behold", data.Range("D3:D50000"), Range("AB4").Cells(i, 1))
    Range("M4").Cells(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(data.Range("AR3:AR50000"), data.Range("B3:B50000"), Range("B4").Cells(i, 1), data.Range("J3:J50000"), "Behold", data.Range("D3:D50000"), Range("AB4").Cells(i, 1))
    Range("N4").Cells(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(data.Range("AU3:AU50000"), data.Range("B3:B50000"), Range("B4").Cells(i, 1), data.Range("J3:J50000"), "Behold", data.Range("D3:D50000"), Range("AB4").Cells(i, 1))
    Range("O4").Cells(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(data.Range("AX3:AX50000"), data.Range("B3:B50000"), Range("B4").Cells(i, 1), data.Range("J3:J50000"), "Behold", data.Range("D3:D50000"), Range("AB4").Cells(i, 1))
```

Thank you in advance guys! :)

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is to isolate the functionality into its own Sub and then parse the data that makes each line different

```
Sub YourSub()
   DoTheSumIf i, "C", "N"
   DoTheSumIf i, "D", "Q"
   DoTheSumIf i, "E", "T"
   DoTheSumIf i, "F", "W"
   DoTheSumIf i, "G", "Z"
   DoTheSumIf i, "H", "AC"
   DoTheSumIf i, "I", "AF"
   DoTheSumIf i, "J", "AI"
   DoTheSumIf i, "K", "AL"
   DoTheSumIf i, "L", "AO"
   DoTheSumIf i, "M", "AR"
   DoTheSumIf i, "N", "AU"
   DoTheSumIf i, "O", "AX"
End Sub
Sub DoTheSumIf(i As Integer, targetRange As String, dataColumn As String)
    Range(targetRange + "4").Cells(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Data.Range(dataColumn + "3:" + dataColumn + "50000"), Data.Range("B3:B50000"), Range("B4").Cells(i, 1), Data.Range("J3:J50000"), "Behold", Data.Range("D3:D50000"), Range("AB4").Cells(i, 1))
End Sub
```

Why would you call Range and then Cell? "Range("D4").Cells(i, 1)". You could just call "Cell" in the first place?

Comment: Hi there,

Didn't know this was even possible. Happy to admit that I am new to VBA and coding, but learning as I go along. Thanks for your contribution!

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from the top:  First, `Range("C4").Cells(i, 1)` is basically just `ActiveSheet.Cells(i+3, 3)`  (Note that if you do not explicitly define the Worksheet, it is implicitly `ActiveSheet`.  You should try to avoid this where possible, just like [using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba))

Similarly, code in the form `data.Range("N3:N50000")` can be written as `data.Range(data.Cells(3, 14), data.cells(50000, 14))`.  This might look longer now, but it will let us cut a lot of code out later.

The last step for iteration 1 is to note your columns are all scaled linearly - they are all consistently 0, 1 or 3 columns apart.

```
For j=1 To 13
    ActiveSheet.Range(i+3, j+2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs( _
        data.Range(data.Cells(3, 3*j+11), data.cells(50000, 3*j+11)), _
        data.Range("B3:B50000"), ActiveSheet.Cells(i+3, 2), _
        data.Range("J3:J50000"), "Behold", _
        data.Range("D3:D50000"), ActiveSheet.Cells(i+3, 28))
Next j
```

---

However, you can **also** use a normal Excel formula, and code in the following format, to do this without *any* loops:

```
With Range(..)
    .Formula = "..."
    .Calculate
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

(You may want to use `Application.Calculate` to disable Automatic Calculation while you do this)

This will require that we know the Minimum and Maximum values of `i` (I have used `min_i` and `max_i`), and the name of the `data` sheet (I have assumed it is `data_sheet`)

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
With ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(min_i+3, 3), ActiveSheet.Cells(max_i+3, 15))
    .Formula = "=SUMIFS(Index(data_sheet!$3:$3, 3*Column()+11):Index(data_sheet!$50000:$50000, 3*Column()+11), " & _
      "data_sheet!$B$3:$B$50000, $B" & cStr(min_i+3) & ", " & _
      "data_sheet!$J$3:$J$50000, ""Behold"", " & _
      "data_sheet!$D$3:$D$50000, $AB" & cStr(min_i+3) & ")"
    .Calculate
    .Value = .Value
End With
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: Hi there. Thanks a bunch for the guide. Very interesting indeed. I do however still struggle. Tried to copy paste your line of code in your first propososal, but I get a compile error saying "Expected: List separator or ). But it sure looks like it all adds up. Hmm.

Comment: @Lelung Sorry, it was missing a `, _` from the SumIf.  Added now

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This was really helpful and feel like I've gained a larger understanding of it! :) May I be so bold to ask another question in another part of my code? 

`For j = 1 To 4
                Range("AC4").Cells(i, j) = Range("Z4").Cells(i, 1) / 4 * j
                        Next j`
This piece of code only gives me the value in the output as a result of when I've run the code, however, I want it to also show the output but preferably also the formula so the user can see how the value has been created? Any idea of how I implement this? :)

Comment: @Lelung Start with fully qualifying your code: `Range("AC4").Cells(i, j).Value = Range("Z4").Cells(i, 1) / 4 * j`, then you can change the `.Value` (implicit/default in your version) to `.Formula = "=$Z4/4 * " & j`  (Also, check whether your code needs brackets - it currently results in `(Z4/4)*j`, not `Z4/(4*j)`)

Comment: Aha. Thanks a bunch. Again it is part of a bigger loop running through rows as well. So it is only first iteration that is Z4. Next will be Z5. How do I change the code to shift downward? I tried `$Z & i` without luck.

Comment: @Lelung Either `.Formula"=$Z" & i & "/4 * " & j`, or use FillDown to put everything in at once (e.g. `Range("AC4:AC100").Formula = "=$Z4/4 * " & j`)

Comment: Many thanks, however, it still does not work. I cannot use the 2nd option you wrote as this is part of an if formula and other rows between 4 and 100 shouldn't put in this formula. I get an error using `Range("AC4").Cells(i, j).Formula "=$Z" & i & "/4 * " & j` "Object doesnt support this property or method". Run time error 438

Comment: @Lelung Sorry, there should be another equals there, between `Formula" and `"=$Z"` (so, `.Formula = "=$Z"`)

Comment: You're a true legend. Thanks a bunch. Really grateful. Is there any specific guide/place you'd start if you want to learn all this " by heart" ?

Comment: Sorry to be so bold and disturb you one last time. Another part of my If code is this formula: `Range("AC4").Cells(i, j) = -Range("Z4").Cells(i, 1) * (4 - j) / 4`. Ive tried rewrite this as. `Range("AC4").Cells(i, j).Formula = "=-$Z" & i + 3 & "*(4 - j) / 4"`. This gives me an output of #NAME? as direct formula is: =-$Z10*(4 - **j**) / 4. Once again. Thanks a bunch for helping

Comment: @Lelung You need to take the `j` out of the quotes, so that VBA adds the *value* to the String which you use as a formula: `Range("AC4").Cells(i, j).Formula = "=-$Z" & i + 3 & "*(4 - " & j & ") / 4"`

Comment: Hello Chonocidal. May I be so bold to ask one last question? I am interested in adding another condition to my sum if formula. I want to add that it should only sum the cells if the value in column I is above 0. Can you please enlighten me? I've tried this without luck:

       `For j = 1 To 13
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 3, j + 2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs( _
        data.Range(data.Cells(3, 3 * j + 11), data.Cells(50000, 3 * j + 11)), _
        data.Range("B3:B50000"), ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 3, 2), _
        data.Range("I3:I50000"), > 0)
        Next j `

Comment: @Lelung The `> 0` needs to be in quotes (`, ">0")`), just like if you were using `SUMIFS` in the Worksheet

Comment: Thanks a bunch again! Very much appreciated! :)